# Input text not align middle when key in data

Tags: css

When I keyin few value, it's now align middle text and cursor. How to fix it? I using twitter boostrap 3.3.7

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
```

[image: right]

[image: error]

Comment: could you add more details of your code and your desired output?

Comment: Do you mean vertically?

Comment: you have over 1k rep. you should know how to properly ask a question here on SO . please provide any relevant code and make a working example of your problem

Comment: Add line-height:5px

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

or

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

if that doesn't help check what line height you have set to see if there is anything odd going on.

Answer (score 0):

Set  padding: 12px 12px 12px 24px; for Class .form-control